# How to get display data in UITableView Section tables with single Array

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsarray, uitableview

I have data on a server which I want to show in the a tableView.

The problem is that I want to show data based on categories so I have array categories which has categories which will be section titles and inside them there data so for display the data in section I have to declare Array.

**e.g.** If there are three categories then we have to make three array to populate data but what if there are more categories as categories are dynamic and come from server.

```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return [categoryArray count] ;
    }
```

And how to set title for section title, as it is in category array, so if it is section one by one in array.

```
    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {


    NSLog(@"Number of Sections");
    if(section == 0)
     return @"Sales";
    if(section == 1)
    return @"Soft Skills";
}
```

How to show data in tableView cells may I create arrays for all the categories?

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


if (section==0)
{

    appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    int count=[resultArray count];

    NSLog(@"resultArry Row Counts is %d",count);

    return [resultArray count];

}
else{
    appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    int count=[resultArrayOne count];

    NSLog(@"resultArry Row Counts is %d",count);

    return [resultArrayOne count];
}
     }




       - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath     
    {

NSLog(@"Table Cell Data");


     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


if (indexPath.section==0) {



    appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


    ObjectData *theCellData = [resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *cellValue =theCellData.sub_Category;
    cell.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetical Bold" size:14];
    NSLog(@"Cell Values %@",cellValue);
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
}

else {



    appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    ObjectData *theCellData = [resultArrayOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *cellValue =theCellData.sub_Category;
    cell.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetical Bold" size:14];

    NSLog(@"Cell Values %@",cellValue);
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    return cell;



   }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since getting the categories from the server does not seem to be your question I base my answer on pre filled arrays for a better visualization.

```
NSMutableArray *categories = @[@"Cat1", @"Cat2"];

// creata a dictionary with all the array for the categorie rows
NSMutableDictionary *rowDict = @{@"Cat1":@[@"Cat1Row1",@"Cat1Row2",@"..."],
                     @"Cat2":@[@"Cat2Row1", @"Cat2Row2",@"..."]
```

Key to this solution is that you use the category string as key for the dictionary.

You can now access the title like this

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return categories[section];
}
```

And access your rows like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // ...
  // create or deque a cell like you normally would do

  // now configure the cell
  cell.textLable.text = [rowDict[categories[indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
}
```

Comment: categories are coming from server so we can not give fixed values and how we will add in dictionary and how will show number of rows in sections

Comment: categories are coming from server so we can not give fixed values and how we will add in dictionary and how will show number of rows in sections

Comment: I know - but I do not know how you obtain them so I opted to „fill“ them for better visualization since getting the arrays does not seem to be your question. You can get them dynamically from the server. That does not matte. My solution solves the problem that you need to access to a dynamic count of catgories. For title and for the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. It'll solve your problem :

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return [categoryArray objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

**EDIT :**

1. First Create a model data class to store data of your categories.
2. Use this model class to feel your `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate function.
3. Instead of creating different-different array for each category. Store this array in one model class. It'll be easy to handle.

Comment: but what to do for display in tableview may creat array

Comment: yes @Rushi but how to sow the data in tableView Cells according to sections

Comment: @ShahzadAli can you show me the code of cellforrowatindexpath?

Comment: yes I have Model Class ObjectData which store the resultArray but how to show items for each section diffrent any idea

Comment: can you please help me out how to do this

Comment: See your each category will have one object of ObjectData class. Add this objects in one NSMutableArray. Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath function retrieve this array element using indexPath.section.

Comment: this is what i have done see in update code but i wan to do it with one array not with three array if i have three sections

Answer (score 0):

use

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [categoryArray objectAtindex:section];
}
```

for section title.

likewise, store the values for each categories in a nsmutable array NSDictionary and display the data for each category in uitableviewcell.

Comment: but how to show data in tableView cells for each section i have to create three arrays or in single array we can show all the things